# Failure validating Xml: The namespace 'X' provided differs from the schema's targetNamespace 'Y'

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm getting the following error while validating an xml document while using IXMLDOMDocument2 (C++):

> The namespace 'http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0' provided differs from the schema's targetNamespace 'http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0/SomeObject' .

The Xml I'm trying to validate is:

```
<id:envelope xmlns:id="http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0/SomeObject" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0 SomeObject.xsd">
    <!-- content -->
</id:envelope>
```

Now I can see that it looks like the xsi:schemaLocation tag has been mangled a bit by the space ("http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0 SomeObject.xsd" seems to be getting interpreted as "http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0"), but I still cant quite understand whats going on as this appears to indicate that the schemaLoaction needs to exactly match the xmlns specified...

- Are spaces not allowed in schema names?
- Does the schemaLoaction need to match the targetNamespace?
- If so, why!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

schemaLocation contais a way of mapping a schema to a place where the schema representation can be found

In this case schemaLocation should contain a pair of strings

```
The schema name - exactly matching the namespace id given

Where it is found in this case a relative file SomeObject.xsd
```

The definitions are in the [W3C schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-repr) see example in section 4.3.2

So a corrected version might be
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0/SomeObject http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0SomeObject.xsd`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual parser you're using, but since the schema location is a URL and URLs are not allowed to contain spaces, perhaps the parser is simply spitting out an incorrect error message. Try proper URL-encoding of the schmea location and see if that helps:

- http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0+SomeObject.xsd or
- http://www.somesite.com/schema/2.0%20SomeObject.xsd